# Join two worksheet to make one in Tableau Desktop

Tags: tableau-api

I have two worksheets in Tableau with same dimensions/column. I want to join those two worksheet to make it one. Can anyone please assist?

Comment: Is it two Tableau worksheets or is it two Excel worksheets loaded into Tableau?

Comment: @ Wizhi, two tableau worksheets in the dashboard.